# Firestore References

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to add a reference field in a document into Firestore using nodejs but i can't do it.

I wrote this code:

```
async function pushType(IDType) {
  const size = await getID();
  const IDClient = (size).toString();
  const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').doc(IDClient);

  await docRef.set({
    ID_Type: firebase.firestore().doc('Types/'+IDType).ref,
  });
}

async function getID(){ 
  const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('Clients').get();
  return snapshot.size;
}
```

The error is: "Function Document.Reference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field ID_Type in document Clients/7)" where 7 is the ID of the document where i want to add the field ID_Type.

Can anyone help me to understand what i'm wrong and how can i fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `firebase.firestore().doc('Types/'+IDType)` returns a [DocumentReference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html).  As you can see from the API docs, there is no property called `ref` on that, so it will be undefined.  In fact, that DocumentReference is exactly what you want to provide to Firestore here.  So just remove `ref`:

```
  await docRef.set({
    ID_Type: firebase.firestore().doc('Types/'+IDType)
  });
```

When you provide a DocumentReference object to a Firestore document like this, it will create a reference type field.